# Rabbitmq multiple consumers receiving same message,instead of round robin

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am trying to use the rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange plugin which seems to work fine to send a delayed message which will be received after a delayed interval. While consuming a message I am supposed to achieve the usual round robin approach in [rabbitmq tutorial 2](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) but what I receive is multiple consumers consuming same message. The client function is where I am doing basic.consume . It is around about the same code as in tutorial 2 for round robin along with delay plugin.

The code works like this - The receive function receives a message which with a particular delay is to be sent back in the queue to be consumed later.
The send message sends the message with a delay.

The problem I am facing is with basic.consume where because of some misconfiguration I suppose I am getting multiple consumers consuming the same message.

Is there something I need to change to achieve multiple consumers avoid processing same requests.

```
class cities:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare("test-x", type="x-delayed-message", arguments={"x-delayed-type":"direct"})
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue='towns_queue')
        self.channel.queue_bind(queue="towns_queue", exchange="test-x", routing_key="towns_queue")
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("rabbitmq")
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler = RotatingFileHandler("logs/Receive.log", maxBytes=100*1024*1024, backupCount=100)
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.errlogger = logging.getLogger("Msg_timer_Error")
        self.errlogger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        errhandler = RotatingFileHandler("logs/towns_error.log", maxBytes=100*1024*1024, backupCount=100)
        self.errlogger.addHandler(errhandler)
        errformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        errhandler.setFormatter(errformatter)

    def call_api(self,url):
        do something

    def server_log(self,msg,value):
        self.logger.info(msg+" : "+str(value))

    def send_msg(self,msg,delay):
        try:
            delay = delay - 40
            self.server_log("Delay Set : ",delay)
            delay *=1000
            self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='test-x',routing_key='towns_queue',body=msg,properties=pika.BasicProperties(headers={"x-delay"\
:delay},delivery_mode=1))
            self.server_log("Msg Sent",msg)
        except:
            self.errlogger.exception(msg)
            self.errlogger.exception(str(traceback.print_exc()))
            pass

    def receive(self,ch, method, properties, body):
        try:
            self.server_log("Received message : ",body)
            self.process(body)
            time.sleep(1)
            ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
            return body
        except:
            self.errlogger.exception(body)
            self.errlogger.exception(str(traceback.print_exc()))
            pass

    def process(self,body):
        delay=self.call_api(body)
        if delay:
           self.send_msg(body,delay)

   def client(self):
        try:
            self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
            self.channel.basic_consume(self.receive,queue='towns_queue',no_ack=False)
            self.channel.start_consuming()
        except:
            self.errlogger.exception(str(traceback.print_exc()))
         pass

    def close(self):
         try:
            self.connection.close()
         except:
            self.errlogger.exception(str(traceback.print_exc()))
           pass

def multiprocess(num_process=4):
    procs = []
    objs = []
    for i in range(4):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=cities().client)
    p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)> 1:
        num_proc = sys.argv[1]
        if num_proc.isdigit():
            num_proc = int(num_proc)
            multiprocess(num_proc)
        else:
            raise Exception ('num_of_processes needs to be an integer.')
    else:
        multiprocess()
```

Any help is appreciated .

**Update :**

Could there be a problem with this:

```
def client(self):
     try:
         self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
         self.channel.basic_consume(self.receive,queue='towns_queue',no_ack=False)
         self.channel.start_consuming()
     except:
         self.errlogger.exception(str(traceback.print_exc()))
         pass
```

Comment: So initially, `receive` get's first message M from somewhere in it's `towns_queue`, then if it detects a delay (in some way) sends again the same message M, and then ACKs the first M, after which it will receive the second M... I must be missing something, otherwise the whole thing is running in circles because it's basically one message being forwarded forever.  Try to make a new queue/routing key for the "second M" message - I don't think this will solve it, but maybe you'll see if there is this circle..

Comment: @cantSleepNow Actually it is supposed to be a circle. There is supposed to be an api call which will do some work on a msg and then send a delayed message. So the same message will have some work done after a delay which is determined by the api call. A delay is somewhere around 140 to 2500 seconds. There are around 8k messages so multiple receivers are needed to handle the requests. But it seems the same message is picked up by multiple receivers

Comment: Ok, so how about sending the forwarded msg with a different routing key? Additionally for test you could append something unique to a msg to see if it really is just one msg being passed around...

Comment: @cantSleepNow I'll write an answer in sometime. The problem caused was because I need to close the connection after sending a message it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the tutorial creates a new connection for every message. I tried working it that way by changing my send_message function where I would create a new client object which would create a new connection to send and close the connection after it is done. So now it works once that change was made.

```
def send_msg(self,msg,delay=0):
    try:
        newClient=cities(0)
        if delay:
            delay = delay - 40
        self.server_log("Delay Set : ",delay)
        delay *=1000
        newClient.channel.basic_publish(exchange="test-x",routing_key='towns_queue',body=msg,properties=pika.BasicProperties(headers={"x-delay":delay},delivery_mode=2,))
        self.server_log("Msg Sent",msg)
        newClient.close()

    except:
        self.errlogger.exception(msg)
        self.errlogger.exception(str(traceback.print_exc()))
        pass
```

Also the __init__ constructor had to be changed to avoid creating loggers everytime which is not a part of the question though.